# Update TFS 2013 to TFS2015 Test Managet Could not connect

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015, microsoft-test-manager

Web update our TFS2013 to TFS2015, most features worked well, but Test Manager could not connect to TFS2015,when create connection, no project collection could be found on server, as shown below:

[image: Test Manager Find no team project collection]

But On web we can open test plans and

[image: Web View Test Plan Ok]

We can open Test Manager from this link:

[image]

I searched from [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/caf6c1ac-fd6b-4f30-8d6c-565199596f52/cant-access-collections-on-a-tfs-2015-server-from-mtm-2013-or-2015?forum=vsmantest) about this problem, and did what they say in that article, but did not resolve my problem.

Comment: Which version of Test Manager are you using? Can you see team project collections when you connect team projects from VS? Do you use the same account in Test Manager as Web Access? Try to install MTM on TFS AT machine, and connect TFS, to see whether you can connect it.

Comment: I installed MTM on TFS AT machine ,and  re-configed AT of TFS ,this problem was resolved, Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to narrow down the issue, please check items below:

1. Check whether the account to connect to TFS in MTM is the same as the account used on web access. Make sure you are using the same account.
2. Try to install MTM on TFS Application Tier machine, and connect TFS, to see whether you can connect it. In this way, you can find out the issue is from TFS side or MTM side.